# Java Regex: make it find longest match?

Tags: java, regex

I am having a regex like this (for illustratory purposes only):

```
(?<number>[0-9]+)|(?<date>[0-9]+\-[0-9]+\-[0-9]+)
```

Applied to `2009-11-10` `Matcher::lookingAt` yields `2009`. Can I pass a flag in the API or in the regular expression to tell the engine to consider the longest matching match?

I do know that in this particular case I could simply reorder the two statements, but I am programmatically assembling the regular expression from several regular expressions and I would love to have their order not play into what matches and what not.

I am using Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

The only (general) way is to re-order the groups. In this case, you *know* that the longest match would be the second group so it needs to be put first. This is because the regex is parsed from left to right to find a match.

Alternatively, for this case, you can wrap the regex with boundary matches marking the beginning and end of the line:

```
^(([0-9]+)|([0-9]+\-[0-9]+\-[0-9]+))$
```

This will only find the longest match if the input matches the whole line.